# Where can I find my inbox

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Purhaps a bit of a strange question, but before I could find my inbox with my past questions at the top left corner in stackexchange. Now you have your inbox next to it, but I can only see my last 5 activities. How can i see older questions?

Probably I am just not looking correct, but would be great if someone can tell me.

---

Thanks for your reply. Strange that you see "see all inbox items" at my desktop at stackoverflow it is not showing. Well with you other message about via the profile page next time.

[image]

Comment: This? http://stackexchange.com/users/2089506/coen?tab=inbox  I clicked on the Inbox at the top of the page, scrolled to the bottom, and clicked "see all inbox items."

Comment: That is it, thanks David. Strange that the inbox button is not shown at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5):

It's still around, at the bottom of the inbox dropdown:

[image: Here]

Also, you can always go to your network profile (link via your profile page on any site) and click the **inbox** link there for the same result.